# manage life cycle of fragments that use in SlidingTabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

in my app i use SlidingTabLayout to make tabs ,my app has three tabs for each tab attach with fragment hence i have three classes extend from Fragment when Run App
show me onCreateView and OnCreate of first and second fragment created together i want to when click on second tab onCreateView and OnCreate of second tab created
because i load things from webservice when click second tab 
like facebook app that happen loading things when click on tab

Comment: does not understand your question

Comment: Facebook App there is four tabs when you click on anyone of tabs 
app loading data depend on tabs click i want to make this in my app 
@sud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using `SlidingTabLayout` combined with `ViewPager`. `ViewPager` by default manages 3 items (curent one on one on the "left"/"right" side) one of which is displayed and 2 others are in idle state. You can't decrease number of such items so the only way for you is to move your web service call from `onCreate`/`onViewCreated` to some other place. For example you may call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in your second fragment and implement your web service call in `onOptionsMenuCreated` callback of your second fragment.

Comment: it works done with me but i want to save instance for items download from web serivce to show them when click on second tab again instance of loading again @Lingviston

Comment: Then implement onSaveInstanceState method of your second fragment and save your items into Bundle there; restore your items using Bundle argument in onCreate/onCreateView etc. methods.; restore your view state according restored items data; don't call webservice again if items data already present in the fragment; use FragmentStatePagerAdapter as adapter for your ViewPager. But actually this is beyound your initial question.

Comment: thanks i know but it is second problem for me Are these steps to do save instance for my items 
1-change  FragmentPagerAdapter into FragmentStatePagerAdapter as adapter for my ViewPager
2-implement save instance method in second activity
3-restore items from bundle on create /CreateView
thanks for help me @Lingviston

Comment: @yousef don't forget not to call web service if your data has already been loaded. Simply check your "data" variable to be non null. And won't forget to accept the answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a predefined method called setOffscreenPageLimit in view pager,

```
setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit)
```

Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state.

For eg.

```
ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

Comment: The TS's issue actually appears due to impossibility of calling setOffscreenPageLimit(0). His fragment which is currently off the screen loads some data from web which he doesn't want to.